# javaw command not supporting special characters

Tags: java, batch-file

I created a bat file that runs on Windows startup, and that launches my jar file

`start javaw -jar "C:/Users/No%c3%a9/Desktop/Workspace/DTK_LTOM/out/artifacts/DTK_LTOM_jar/DTK_LTOM.jar"` (see, here it replaces "é" with %c3%a9, and when i replace the "é" by myself then it still replaces it with weird symbols)

But I have got a problem: when I launch it, nothing happens. So I tried to write "java" instead of "javaw" to see what the problem was. I have got a French first name containing a "é" character and it seems to be the problem, because it shows an error dialog window, and the "é" is replaced with some weird characters. Then my question is: How can I make either the bat file or the jar file be able to work with special characters.

```
public class Listener {
    JDA jda;
    String roaming = System.getenv("APPDATA");

    public Listener() {
        //jda = Grabber.getInstance().getJda();

        String path = roaming + "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\";
        File fi = new File(path + "javalaunchauto.bat");
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fi));
            writer.write("start javaw -jar " + Grabber.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().substring(1));
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //here just to see when the jar is opened
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Listener();

    }
}
```

I found something useful for that: Using the `class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()` method is risky, if you don't decode it after that. I did decode it with `URLDecoder.decode(str,"UTF-8")`, with str as the path of my jar file with `class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()`. I thought it was going to work, but in fact it does add "é" into the batch file, but it still shows an error when opening it. (`Error: Unable to access jarfile C:/Users/NoÚ(instead of Noé)/Desktop/etc.`)

Comment: What about your codepage? if you type `chcp` in your Command Prompt window and press the `[ENTER]` key, what does it output?

Comment: It outputs "850 active code pages"

Comment: If it is possible, i would like to change it with the code, because it must be compatible with any computer

Comment: `getLocation().getPath()` *does not* return a file name.  You cannot convert a URL to a file that way.  Use `getLocation().toURI()` instead, and pass that URI to a `File` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Compo, I explored the `chcp` command. In fact it is possible to change the number of different characters you can have in a batch file. You just have to precise after `chcp` the number of characters.

`chcp 1252` seems to work, as it is referring to latin alphabet and chinese alphabet (I think).

Anyways, as it is a command working in the Command Prompt, you can write it in a batch file.

Here is a before/after :

Before:

```
start javaw -jar C:/Users/Noé/Desktop/Workspace/DTK_LTOM/out/artifacts/DTK_LTOM_jar/DTK_LTOM.jar
```

After:

```
chcp 1252
start javaw -jar C:/Users/Noé/Desktop/Workspace/DTK_LTOM/out/artifacts/DTK_LTOM_jar/DTK_LTOM.jar
```

Thanks Compo and I hope it helped some people.